# Notification drawer pops up at random

Tags: notifications

I have a new Nokia 5.4 TA-1337 with Android 10. Every so often, the notification drawer that's supposed to come up when swiping down from the top of the screen (darkening the screen, showing the Wifi, Bluetooth, Do Not Disturb, Flashlight, Auto-Rotate and Battery Saver buttons/tiles, as well as any outstanding notifications) comes up at random.

It doesn't appear to be related to whether or not there are any new notifications. Sometimes it's also the other way around (the notification drawer disappearing when I actually wanted it).

[image: screenshot of the notifications overlay]

It happens *constantly* (multiple times while writing this question alone).

What causes this? What can I do to fix it?

Comment: Unrelated to this device model but based on my experience with some devices: 1) Ghost touches; to test this, turn on Developer options - Show taps & Pointer location, then see if there are "touches" detected even if you don't touch the screen, or 2) Gesture shortcut, like swiping up/down on the fingerprint scanner on the back of Pixel 3a

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Some devices have the "swipe fingerprint for notifications" feature.**

On some devices (e.g. Nokia, Google Pixel), swiping down/up the fingerprint scanner on the back may show/hide the notification panel. This is known as the "swipe fingerprint for notifications" feature.

> [image]
>
> **Swipe fingerprint for notifications**
>
> To check your notifications, swipe down on the fingerprint sensor on the back of your phone.

The setting for this feature can be accessed from:

- Settings - System - Gestures - Swipe fingerprint for notifications
- Settings - Apps & notifications - Notifications - Advanced - Swipe fingerprint for notifications
- (or search for "swipe")

Comment: If that isn't the cause, is there a "sensitivity" setting as my wife's phone seems to register touches occasionally when her finger gets close, but doesn't touch the screen. I haven't tried checking for "Ghost Touches" yet..